# Is it possible to change font DPI in 11.04?

Tags: 11.04, dpi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I change the font DPI settings?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/60044/how-do-i-change-the-font-dpi-settings)

With the introduction of the new global system settings application, it seems like they forgot about this (along with many other important) features.

Is there still a way to do this in 11.04?