# Ubuntu 12.04 resolution is correct, but windows are pudgy and bloated compared to 11.04. ATI Driver is screwed up

Tags: ati, multiple-monitors, resolution

I am not a noob to Linux, but I am sure as heck not a pro. 12.04 has nearly all the 'tweaks' out of the box, that I had to manually do myself with prior ubuntu releases, and I am grateful for this. BUT:

I installed 12.04 on my SONY VAIO VPCEE23FX yesterday, and after fooling with unity, ultimately decided o go back to GNOME Classic. Unity was all-new to me (I resisted upgrading to 11.10 cuz of it) and so I didn't really notice any change in resolution.

However, as soon as I went back to GNOME Classic, I saw the change. Even though my resolution is correct (according to 'Displays') at 1366 x 786 (16x9), everything appears bigger and pudgier. The clarity is just fine. Words are sharp as ever, and there is no fuzzy or blurred effect anywhere, but windows are bigger, menus are bigger; basically it cut my workspace size in half, because everything takes up more space now.

Back in the day, when I installed 11.04, I was able to use the third-party ATI drivers from the 'Additional Drivers' tool for my SONY and they worked great. Even with Dual-monitors thru VGA. I knew I would have to use them for 12.04 too, in order to have the graphic acceleration I should get. However, the ATI post-release package fails to install (something about var/log/ blah blah) and the other ATI release installs, but royally screws up my dual-monitor set-up. (resolution parameters are wrong error messages galore, et cetera)

Bottom line: ATI Drivers aren't working right (I need those two screens) Ubuntu's drivers seem to be getting the resolution just fine, yet everything is bloated and bigger than it used to be. So big that it bugs me, because I know how much space I used to have on my desktop for windows and such. Also, even when I have the proprietary ATI driver installed and activated, my resolution options are the same as generic, and everything is just as bloated as without the ATI driver.

It is at least, clear and legible, but I know that two days from now, I'm gonna be cursing at my workspace because I don't have the room I used to, and get my shorts in a knot because I feel claustrophobic.

I have no idea how to fix the ATI errors with dual-monitors, and I have no other resolution options with the generic driver that can tighten the windows with the max 1366x786.

I am horrible at generating error codes and tracking outputs. I can't diagnose problems to save my life using scripts. I usually copy the error bubble, and Google the heck out of it. This time, because 12.04 is new, my lack of skill profits me even less.

Help?

Answer (score 1):

Since your resolution appears to be set to the display's native one, try forcing the DPI setting to 96 or less. It should apply to window dimensions and font sizes in most applications.

I'm using XFCE, the graphical interface to change the DPI setting is **xfce4-appearance-settings**.

For Gnome 2, this seems to do it:

[Is it possible to change font DPI in 11.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/59850/is-it-possible-to-change-font-dpi-in-11-04)

And for Gnome 3:

[How do I change the font DPI settings?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/60044/how-do-i-change-the-font-dpi-settings)